# sql query works fine in mysql but fails in HSQL with BadSqlGrammarException in spring-boot test

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, spring-boot, hsqldb

I have a `spring-boot` service that I am writing unit tests.
The service executes following method as part of API. I tested API manually through Rest Client and I could see it working.

```
 public int doProessing(String name) {
        String sql = "DELETE BS FROM FOO.TABLE1 BS JOIN FOO.TABLE2 BM on BM.SURR_KEY = BS.SURR_KEY WHERE BM.NAME = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{StringUtils.upperCase(name)});
    }
```

when I write a unit-test that uses HSQL, I get following exception.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE BS FROM FOO.TABLE1 BS JOIN FOO.TABLE2 BM on BM.SURR_KEY = BS.SURR_KEY WHERE BM.NAME = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: BS required: FROM in statement [DELETE BS FROM FOO.TABLE1 BS JOIN FOO.TABLE2 BM on BM.SURR_KEY = BS.SURR_KEY WHERE BM.NAME = ?]
```

I don't understand why HSQL is complaining for this sql which works fine in MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Every dbms have their own syntax.  Your statement would probably fail too in SQL Server or Oracle.  Read the documentation for HSQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as it uses a JOIN for a DELETE. The HSQLDB syntax is below:

```
DELETE FROM FOO.TABLE1 BS WHERE BS.SURR_KEY IN (SELECT BM.SURR_KEY FROM FOO.TABLE2 BM WHERE BM.NAME = ?)
```